# How to Hide "Filter By Name" search box under filterByColumn in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, css-tables

I'm following a tutorial, but I would like to hide or remove this search box.
I've looked through the Internet and seems I haven't found a solution yet.

I want to get rid of these two search boxes:

[image]

My Code is like this:

```
 Vue.use(VueTables.client, {
  compileTemplates: true,
  filterByColumn: true,

  sortable: false,
  texts: {
    filter: "Search:"
  },
  datepickerOptions: {
    showDropdowns: true
  },
  ---
});
```

Is there any filterByColumn option to hide these two boxes?

Full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/e0uLphvk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ikbelkirasan/e0uLphvk/2/).

Basically, you need to add the columns you want to filter to `options.filterable` array in your Vue data.

```
new Vue({
  // ..
  data: {
    // ..
    options: {
      //...
      filterable: ['manufacturer', 'birth_date'],
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: btw, i'm trying to move the whole file to codepen to see if it works. However, the table just doesn't show up. Is there anything I should add to show the table? the link is here : https://codepen.io/dennis-leeyinghui/pen/RgXOKL

Comment: That's because you're using `Vue 1.x` in your original jsfiddle version. Codepen uses the latest version of Vue. So, you should switch to `Vue 2.x` instead or use the exact version as you jsfiddle. Anyways, here is a working codepen https://codepen.io/ikbelkirasan/pen/zzgXzv

Comment: Words can't describe how grateful I am :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: My pleasure! happy to help :)

Comment: Just got another question (sorry for asking too many newbie questions).

How do I remove the "Records & Dropdown list" on the top-right corner of the table? I've tried a few vue table options, but they didn't really work. 

Are these dropdown lists, search boxes set to be visible by default? Thanks!
link: https://codepen.io/ikbelkirasan/pen/zzgXzv

Comment: No problem. Just create a new question for this issue and I will answer it.

Comment: Well, to hide records dropdown box, you can add this to your `created` function:

```this.$el.querySelector('.VueTables__limit').hidden = true```

Check this out: https://codepen.io/ikbelkirasan/pen/zzgXzv